# expo When I run the installed app after building it on my device, the app does not work at all. (Ends immediately) I want to know all possibilities

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

When I run it on my device with expo go or when I run it on an emulator, no errors are found and it works properly.

However, when I installed the apk on my device after building it using
`eas build --profile production --platform android`
, it does not work at all.
As soon as you launch the app, it closes (stops) immediately.
I'm curious about all the possibilities or ways to determine why this error occurs.

I use React native expo.
this is info of my app.

```
package.json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.4",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```
eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.4.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

```
app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myapp",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```